# Why are %LAUNCHER_PATH% and %LAUNCHER_ARGS% not being replaced in web.config when publishing my asp.net Core site?

Tags: visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core

When I publish my Asp.Net Core site, the web.config file is copied as-is and the variables %LAUNCHER_PATH% and %LAUNCHER_ARGS% aren't getting replaced.  I'm not sure how this happened, but I know that it worked before.  I think it has something to do with the site project itself because I have another site in the same solution that I can publish without issue.

So, would anyone know why this is happening and what I can do to fix it?

Comment: Those should be replaced by the tool Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration.Tools. Do you have that set up in your project?

Comment: I didn't, though I'm sure I did at one point.  I re-added the package, but the site still doesn't publish correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I paid more attention to the error message I was receiving when the site was building and tried to do as it suggested, namely installing the latest .NET Core sdk from [here](https://www.microsoft.com/net/download/core).  After the installation, my site now publishes without any problems.  The process must have been erroring out before those variables were populated.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your tooling is set up right. See:
https://github.com/aspnet/Templates/blob/1.0.0/src/BaseTemplates/EmptyWeb/project.json#L15
https://github.com/aspnet/Templates/blob/1.0.0/src/BaseTemplates/EmptyWeb/project.json#L47

Comment: I made sure that project.json looks like the example you linked, but it's still not publishing correctly.